# How to force text go outside table cell without changing its size

Tags: html, css

I need to place a text with no spaces into left cell of my table, but I want to keep the size of the cell. Below is graphics example of what I want to achieve:

[image: table cell graphics explanation]

I tried different word-wrap settings but it only works for divs and not the cell table.

Comment: `table-layout:fixed` on table?

Comment: Please provide html and css.

Answer (score 1):

fix the size of left div with css using width.